# No data passed in to header function when handling PHP SoapServer headers

Tags: php, soap

My header method (AuthHeader) is being called on the server side but the param value is an object and prints out as '1'. I am expecting a 'ticket' string (as in $header->ticket) as defined in the wsdl below.

```
public function AuthHeader($header)
{
    try {
        error_log(print_r($header));
        ...
```

wsdl definition...

```
        <element name="AuthHeader">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="ticket" type="xsd:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
```

I think I have everything setup correctly and dumping the incoming request shows that the header is correct.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/SOAP/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:AuthHeader><ns1:ticket>myticketval</ns1:ticket></ns1:AuthHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body>...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fyi, if you want to log the output of a print_r(), pass TRUE as the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the object as a string.  I have had to do that in the past with SimpleXML objects, and it may be the same in your case.

```
print (string)$header;
```